# jQuery validation errorPlacement - can't remove error once corrected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

hoping you can help me out! I'm having trouble removing an error once the user has corrected their error. For example, validating an email field. every character press keeps appending an error as many times as necessary until it's validated. Here is a snippet:

```
$( "#bookings" ).validate({
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
      message: {
        email: {
          required: "field is required",
          email: "invalid email"
        },
      errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('div#results')), wrapper: 'li',

        errorContainer: $('div#results'),

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $('#results').append(error);
        }
      success: function(error){ 
          error.remove(); 
      }

});



<div id="results">

</div>
<form name="bookings" id="bookings" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="item" style="clear:left;">
        <label>E Mail *</label>
        <input id="femail" name="email" type="text">
    </div>
</form>
```

What I want to achieve is for the error to appear ONCE.So far I have successful removal. but the error keeps appending itself over and over again until validation is successful.

Comment: I've managed to remove it using the following
success: function(error){
    error.remove();
      
   }
But even still, on every character press, the error pops up multiple times until validation is true.

Comment: can you replicate this on a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/hGNRG/

**JS:-**

```
$("#bookings").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        message: {
            email: {
                required: "field is required",
                email: "invalid email"
            },
            errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('div#results')), wrapper: 'li',
            errorContainer: $('div#results'),

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $('#results').append(error);
            },
            success: function (error) {
                error.remove();
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @AkiraDawson - Does this answer your problem?

Comment: Thanks heaps! You definitely got me out of a pickle! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your `errorLabelContainer`,`wrapper`,`errorContainer`,`errorPlacement`, and `success` options and put this instead:

```
  wrapper: 'li',
  errorLabelContainer:$('#results')
```

The stuff you had is basically duplicating (poorly) what the Validation plugin does by default.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/hGNRG/1/ (hat tip to @wiz-kid for creating the fiddle).